# zref resets equation numbers in `align`

Tags: equations, align, zref

The example shows that when I use the `zref-perpage` package, the equation numbers are reset (start at 1) when entering an `align` environment. The `perpage` package doesn't have this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thezpage.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}
Equation:
\begin{equation}
  1<2
\end{equation}


Align:
\begin{align}
  2&<3\\
  &<4
\end{align}


Equation:
\begin{equation}
  4<5
\end{equation}


Align:
\begin{align}
  5&<6\\
  &<7
\end{align}


Equation:
\begin{equation}
  7<8
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zref-perpage` gets confused because the material in `align` is processed twice. A simple patch fixes the issue: stepping the internal counter only in the non-measuring phase.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\ZREF@@perpage@step}
 {\global\advance\c@zref@unique\ltx@one}
 {\ifmeasuring@\else\global\advance\c@zref@unique\ltx@one\fi}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\zmakeperpage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thezpage.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}
Equation:
\begin{equation}
  1<2
\end{equation}


Align:
\begin{align}
  2&<3\\
  &<4
\end{align}


Equation:
\begin{equation}
  4<5
\end{equation}


Align:
\begin{align}
  5&<6\\
  &<7
\end{align}


Equation:
\begin{equation}
  7<8
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ha this patch made it into a new release of `zref`?